# Maxima spline result not changing in loop

Tags: maxima

I'm trying to iterate over 2 parameters to get two splines for each pair. The code:

```
y_arr:[0.2487,0.40323333333333,0.55776666666667,0.7123]$
str_h_arr:[-0.8,-1.0,-1.2,-1.4]$
z_points:[0,0.1225,0.245,0.3675,0.49,0.6125,0.735,0.8575,0.98,1.1025,1.225,1.3475,1.47,
1.5925,1.715,1.8375,1.96,2.0825,2.205,2.26625,2.3275,2.3765,2.401,2.4255,2.43775,
2.4451,2.448775,2.45]$
length(a)$
length(b)$
load(interpol)$
for y_k:1 thru length(a) do (
    for h_k:1 thru length(b) do (
        y:y_arr[y_k],
        str_h:str_h_arr[h_k],
        bot_startpoints: [[-2.45,0],[0,y],[2.45,0]],
        top_startpoints: [[-2.45,str_h_min],[0,y+str_h],[2.45,str_h_min]],
        spline: cspline(bot_startpoints),
        bot(x):=''spline,

        print(bot(0))
    )
);
```

//Part with top spline is skipped.

For all iterations output is now the same: `0.7123`
What I want to get is two splines like in picture [image: example of spline]
Members of `y_arr` are y values in x=0, `str_h_arr`: height between splines in x=0. 
So bot(0) should give me all values from y_arr. 
If i don't use loop and just give this block values of y_k and h_k, it's working properly. 
Can anybody point me to where I'm (or Maxima is) wrong with using loop with cspline?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that quote-quote (two single quotes, `''`) is applied only once, when it is read in input; it is not applied every time the expression in evaluated in the loop.

Looks like you need only to evaluate the spline at x = 0 and nothing else. So I'll suggest `ev(spline, x=0)` to evaluate it. You can also construct a lambda expression and evaluate that.

Here is the program after I've revised it as described above. Also, it is simpler and clearer to write `for y in y_arr do (...)` rather than making use of an explicit index for `y_arr`.

```
y_arr:[0.2487,0.40323333333333,0.55776666666667,0.7123]$
str_h_arr:[-0.8,-1.0,-1.2,-1.4]$
z_points:[0,0.1225,0.245,0.3675,0.49,0.6125,0.735,0.8575,0.98,1.1025,1.225,1.3475,1.47,
1.5925,1.715,1.8375,1.96,2.0825,2.205,2.26625,2.3275,2.3765,2.401,2.4255,2.43775,
2.4451,2.448775,2.45]$
load(interpol)$
for y in y_arr do (
  for str_h in str_h_arr do (
    bot_startpoints: [[-2.45,0],[0,y],[2.45,0]],
    top_startpoints: [[-2.45,str_h_min],[0,y+str_h],[2.45,str_h_min]],
    spline: cspline(bot_startpoints),
    print (ev (spline, x=0))));
```

This is the output I get:

```
0.2487 
0.2487 
0.2487 
0.2487 
0.40323333333333 
0.40323333333333 
0.40323333333333 
0.40323333333333 
0.55776666666667 
0.55776666666667 
0.55776666666667 
0.55776666666667 
0.7123 
0.7123 
0.7123 
0.7123
```